# How can I wrap the content in the AutoCompleteTextView in android

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I want to support `AutoCompleteTextView` in android. How can wrap the content of the view data to the width of the screen?

Comment: use `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

Answer (score 0):

Use this, you can set minimum width and maximum width in "dp"

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:maxWidth=""
android:mixWidth=""
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..
you can give **fixed width and height into dp.**

```
 <AutoCompleteTextView
  android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:ems="10" />
```